# create a grid and extract species and climate data

Tags: r

I am looking for R support to arrange my dataset  which I tried and failed in Arc GIS.

I have 6 bioclimatic variables and 14 species. I want to create a 10kmX10Km grid to Australia (like a fishnet in Arc gis) and extract presence/absence ( 1/0) of species in each grid and mean/ or values for each variable.
Eg

```
Grid number or centroid coordinates Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Sp4 Bio1    Bio2
1                                    1  1   0   1    25      15
2                                    0  0   1   0    19      20
3                                    1  0   0   0    25      30
4                                    0  0   1   1    18      25
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Have you tried searching "create grid r" and "extract points grid raster r"? You will likely need packages `sp` and possibly `raster` and maybe `rgeos`.

Comment: First thing to do is get some actual coordinates for those grid numbers. Think the question is too broad at the moment and agree the questioner would benefit by initially studying the documentation of pkg:sp.